# Sum of array and matrix

Tags: r, arrays

I want to sum each layer of an array with a matrix with the same number of rows and columns.

```
array1<-array(1,dim=c(3,3,2))
matrix1<-matrix(2,nrow=3,ncol=3)

> array1
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

> matrix1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2
```

Required result:

```
>sumofarrays
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3
```

It works with the code below but I am sure there is a nicer way:

```
sumofarrays <- array1 + array(matrix1, dim=c(nrow(matrix1),   
               ncol(matrix1), dim(array1)[3] ))
```

Comment: What do you mean by layers? Can you add a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: You can use `apply` on the third dimension, like so: `apply(array1, 3, "+", matrix1, simplify = FALSE)`; but it returns a list

Comment: Also, well, in your example, just `array1 + 2` would work

Comment: Please create an example where each of the elements in the array and in the matrix are different and show the expected result.

Comment: This is sometimes called array broadcasting. Being also a MATLAB user, I find the lack of this capability in R frustrating at times. I usually try to arrange my arrays up front to be 2D instead of broadcasting with 3D+ arrays. A couple base options are `sweep` and `apply`, but they're painfully slow compared to MATLAB. The `rray` package is easy to use, but also quite slow. The best general option for speed is the `einsum` package (read about `einsum_generator` in the documentation), but you have to get familiar with the Einstein summation notation.

Answer (score 1):

A few options if the goal is to sum each of matrices along the third dimension of a 3D array (`a` here) with a separate matrix (`m`).

```
a <- array(1:18, c(3, 3, 2))
m <- matrix(0.5:8.5, 3, 3)

(ma <- sweep(a, 1:2, -m))
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.5  7.5 13.5
#> [2,]  3.5  9.5 15.5
#> [3,]  5.5 11.5 17.5
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 10.5 16.5 22.5
#> [2,] 12.5 18.5 24.5
#> [3,] 14.5 20.5 26.5
identical(ma, a + rep(m, dim(a)[3]))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(ma, simplify2array(apply(a, 3, "+", m, simplify = FALSE)))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(ma, array(c(a) + c(m), c(3, 3, 2)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Benchmarking:

```
a <- array(runif(1e5), c(100, 100, 10))
m <- matrix(runif(1e4), 100, 100)

bench::mark(
  sweep(a, 1:2, -m),
  a + rep(m, dim(a)[3]),
  simplify2array(apply(a, 3, "+", m, simplify = FALSE)),
  array(c(a) + c(m), dim(a))
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression                           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 "sweep(a, 1:2, -m)"                486µs  637.6µs     1544.     1.6MB     58.5
#> 2 "a + rep(m, dim(a)[3])"            220µs  348.7µs     2843.   781.3KB     54.5
#> 3 "simplify2array(apply(a, 3, \"…   1.27ms   1.74ms      564.    4.96MB     90.4
#> 4 "array(c(a) + c(m), dim(a))"     379.8µs 622.45µs     1498.     1.6MB     58.9
```

`rep` seems to be the best option for this specific application.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

jblood94 mentioned sweep

```
sweep(x = array1,
      MARGIN = 3,
      FUN = "+",
      STATS = matrix1,
      check.margin = FALSE
      )
```